# How to translate variables in magento admin site block

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Here is a variable in new order email template. It's showing in English where as the order was taken place from another store. Is it possible to be translated.
The variable is:

{{var order.getShippingDescription()}}

And it shows "Aramex International" currently in every store.

Answer (score 0):

The email template in Magento is not designed to work like Magento's translator methods `Mage::helper('foobar')->__('Text to be translated')`

This is how the template works:

In your Magento installation root:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── code
│   ├── design
│   ├── etc
│   └── locale
│       ├── en_US
│       │   └── template
│       │       └── email
│       │           └── account_new.html
│       └── zh_HK
│           └── template
│              └── email
│                  └── account_new.html
├── downloader
├── media
└── ...
```

**Every folder (`en_US`, `zh_HK`) located inside `app/locale` should match a setting in `Configuration > General > General > Locale` for each store.**

E.g:

For store #1: English (United States) <--> en_US;

For store #2: Chinese (Hong Kong SAR China) <--> zh_HK

After that your mail templates (e.g `app/locale/{code}/template/email/account_new.html`) will be used by the corresponding store {code} on which the client is using the site.

That says, if your customer is creating account from store #1, the  template from en_US will be used, and if he/she is creating account from store #2, the template from zh_HK is used.